# How can I grep in source files for some text?

Tags: bash, grep, pipe, xargs

At the moment I'm using two commands, I'm sure there must be a better way...

```
wim@wim-acer:~/ffmpeg$ find . -name "*.h" -print0 | xargs -0 grep -i invalid\ preset
wim@wim-acer:~/ffmpeg$ find . -name "*.c" -print0 | xargs -0 grep -i invalid\ preset
```

Comment: does `-name '*.[ch]'` work?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[ack](http://betterthangrep.com/) (or, on Debian/Ubuntu, ack-grep) will ignore non-source files like version control or binaries. Very useful.

to search just .c and .h files, as above:

```
ack-grep -i --cc "invalid preset"
```

the `--cc` (the longer form is `--type cc`) only looks at .c .h & .xs files. The full list of filetypes is viewable with `ack-grep --help type`. Most of the time, you won't particularly need the `--type`, as it will generally only have the files to search, and then files you won't see by default, like binaries, backups and version control files.

Answer (score 5):

The `grep` program itself can search recursively and also accepts an option to search only certain files. The following is equivalent to your two `find` commands.

```
grep -Ri --include=*.[ch] invalid\ preset .
```

Comment: This worked for me when I got rid of the brackets

Answer (score 1):

The find command can call grep itself.

```
find . \( -name "*.c" -o -name "*.h" \) -exec grep -i "invalid preset" {} \; -print
```

and variations of thereof.

Comment: Changed it to the obvious variation. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
grep -rni --include=*.{cpp,h,hpp,c} <your_pattern>
```

if you are using git and vscode, you can exclude these dirs:

```
grep -rni --include=*.{cpp,h,hpp,c} --exclude-dir=.{git,vscode} <your_pattern>
```

if you need to exclude some files' extensions

```
grep -rni --include=*.{cpp,h,hpp,c} --exclude=*.{exe,obj,make,dll,lib} --exclude-dir=.{git,vscode} <your_pattern>
```

small hint from grep help

```
  -i, --ignore-case         ignore case distinctions in patterns and data
  -w, --word-regexp         match only whole words
    -x, --line-regexp         match only whole lines
  -n, --line-number         print line number with output lines
  -r, --recursive           like --directories=recurse
  --include=GLOB        search only files that match GLOB (a file pattern)
    --exclude=GLOB        skip files that match GLOB
    --exclude-dir=GLOB    skip directories that match GLOB
```

Comment: and of course you can add these command to aliases

Answer (score 0):

I can add something like this to your `~/.bashrc`

```
alias cppgrep='grep -Ri "--include=*.[hc]" "--include=*.cpp" "--include=*.hpp"'
```