# How do you search for specific text in specific file types?

Tags: linux, find, grep, file-types, recursive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I grep in source files for some text?](https://superuser.com/questions/327845/how-can-i-grep-in-source-files-for-some-text)

What's the command to search for specific text in specific file types, recursively, under the current directory?

Comment: What do you want returned? the line the text is on? the name of the file the text is in?

Comment: @MaQleod: That would be good (filename + linenumber + snippet), if that's possible.

Comment: @slhck: ack-grep is not installed; I don't have the permissions to install it.

Comment: You wouldn't need `ack-grep`, you can use the examples in the question as a started (just like I said), i.e. the `find | xargs | grep` lines. For the specific output, `man grep` is always useful to read.

Comment: @slhck: Thanks, so I did `grep -r --include=*.<type> "<string>" .`, which worked.  Unfortunately, the man page is not very straightforward in mentioning the trailing dot.

Comment: Yeah, the trailing dot is your current directory. Because it's basically `grep <option> <something> <somewhere>`, in your case `<somewhere>` is just `.` :)

Comment: This is not a duplicate question. It is asking how to search over specific file types.  This is very irritating because I want an answer to the question and there is no answer on this site because this question has been marked as a duplicate!

Answer (score 14):

```
find . -type f -name '*.extension' | xargs grep "string"
```

This command runs *find* on the local directory (.) for any files with names matching the pattern *.extension, then runs *grep* for "string" on the results of the *find*.  Note that *find* is inherently recursive.  As long as you can differentiate the files that you want from the files you don't based on name, this should work for you.

Comment: This breaks with filenames containing spaces, you should use the `print0` option to be safer.

Comment: Only `find -print0` will not help, also use `xargs -0`: `find . -type f -name "*.ext" -print0 | xargs -0 grep "string"`

Comment: I'd recommend invoking `grep` with the `-s` (`--no-messages`) switch. Otherwise you may get a flood of errors messages that can mask actual matches.

Answer (score 0):

To list the file name, line number in specified file and line the text appears:

```
for x in *.xxx; do [ -r $x ] | cat $x | grep -n TEXT | xargs printf "$x:%s\n";done
```

It will only run in the current directory, but it will format it nicely for you.